# mongo PHP app error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message ''.' not allowed in key

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have the following PHP array:

```
array (size=9)
  'script_desc' => string 'Test Script' (length=21)
  'script_date' => string 'May 11 2016 15:40:48' (length=20)
  'log_date' => string 'May 12 2016 09:17:58' (length=20)
  'name' => string 'test name' (length=2)
  'type' => string 'location_status' (length=15)
  'status' => boolean false
  'test.server.1' => 
    array (size=1)
      'packages' => 
        array (size=2)
          'package1' => 
            array (size=4)
              'package_name' => string 'package1' (length=10)
              'current_version' => string 'package1-1.4.26-r1' (length=20)
              'latest_version' => string '1.4.26-r1' (length=9)
              'package_status' => string '=' (length=1)
          'package2' => 
            array (size=4)
              'package_name' => string 'package2' (length=14)
              'current_version' => string 'package2-0.31.1-r1' (length=24)
              'latest_version' => string '0.31.1-r2' (length=9)
              'package_status' => string '<' (length=1)
  'test.server.2' => 
    array (size=1)
      'packages' => 
        array (size=2)
          'package1' => 
            array (size=4)
              'package_name' => string 'package1' (length=16)
              'current_version' => string 'package1-0.35.1-r0' (length=26)
              'latest_version' => string '0.35.1-r0' (length=9)
              'package_status' => string '=' (length=1)
          'package3' => 
            array (size=4)
              'package_name' => string 'package3' (length=3)
              'current_version' => string 'package3-5.3.2-r0' (length=33)
              'latest_version' => string '5.3.2-r0' (length=8)
              'package_status' => string '=' (length=1)
  '_id' => float 5
```

Here's the code that I use to try to insert this array into my mongo database:

```
 68 function add_history_record($location)
 69 {
 70         $m = new MongoClient("mongodb://10.1.1.1:27017");
 71         $db = $m->mymongodb;
 72         $collection = $db->mycollection;
 73         $location['_id'] = getNextSequence("locationid");
 74         $cursor = $collection->insert($location);
 75 var_dump($cursor);
 76 }
```

The error message I'm getting is this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message ''.' not
>   allowed in key: test.server.1' in
>   /var/www/html/mongotestapp/inventory.php on
>   line 74

**What I've tried So Far:**

To prove to myself that I can have keys with "." in it, I used robomongo to add the following document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("573483ae3747106e60a087f9"),
    "test.server.1.1" : 123
}
```

It saved the document in my collection no problems. 
I'm not sure what I'm missing in my PHP code... 
Any suggestions?

**EDIT 1:**

I've changed my code to include the following:

```
 68 function add_playbook_history_record($location)
 69 {
 70         $m = new MongoClient("mongodb://10.1.1.1:27017");
 71         $db = $m->phonesys;
 72         $collection = $db->inventory;
 73         $location['_id'] = getNextSequence("locationid");
 74         printf($location['_id']); 
 75         echo "<pre>".json_encode($location)."</pre>";
 76         $cursor = $collection->insert($location, array("w"=>1));
 77 
 78 //      $cursor = $collection->insert($location, array("w" => 0,"j"=>true));
 79 }
```

I can see that the system is generating a legit location id. 
I also took the json formatted output and tested in jsonlint to make sure it's properly formatted etc. 
Lastly, I started playing with the write options.  When I enable line 78, the system doesn't return any error messages, but the records are not added to the database.  But when I set w=1, it fails with the same error message about the key.
I've been playing around with the different options and reading this: http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.writeconcerns.php
but if you have any tips I'm all ears.

I don't have any shards or other servers. Just one main mongodb server running right now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not have a `.` in your key names as the error message tells you.

MongoDB accepts this directly, but you would not be able to query against these field names as in queries, the dot has a special meaning:

```
// document
{foo:{bar:"baz"}}}

// query
db.col.find( { 'foo.bar' : 'baz' } );
```

All official drivers guard against putting a `.` (and other chars) in key names, and hence the PHP driver correctly rejects this.

Comment: Ok.  I guess I got confused / didn't think that the error message was accurate since manual tests all worked.  But thanks for the response!